# How to set initial transform rotate value to the middle of the interpolation range in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
let wiggleRef = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

function wiggle(count){
  
   if (count == 6) return;
       
   Animated.sequence([
            Animated.timing(wiggleRef, { toValue: 1, duration: 300, easing: Easing.linear }),
            Animated.timing(wiggleRef, { toValue: 0, duration: 300}),
            Animated.timing(wiggleRef, { toValue: .5, duration: 300})

        ]).start(e=> {if (e.finished) wiggle(count + 1)});
        
}
const wiggleInterpol = wiggleRef.interpolate({
   inputRange: [0,1],
   outputRange: ['-6deg', '6deg']
});

         <AnimatedIcon 
           name='pill' 
           color='black' 
           style={{ transform: [{rotate: wiggleInterpol /* want to set this to initially be 0.5 or '0deg' */}], paddingBottom: marginRightRef, fontSize:logoRef, marginRight: marginRightRef, marginTop: marginTopRef}}
         >
         </AnimatedIcon>
```

In the code above, I want my Animated.Icon component to start with a 0 degree rotation, but since I need to animate a rotation alternating from -6deg to 6deg, the component initially renders before the animation at -6deg. How can I make it start at 0deg?

Answer (score 0):

Consider controlling the animation state as a boolean value:

```
const [animatingState, setAnimatingState] = React.useState(false);
   

 function wiggle(count) {
        if (count == 6) {
          setAnimatingState(false);
          return;
        }
    setAnimatingState(true);
...
```

Change the state inside your function and set the default value as the following code shows:

```
<AnimatedIcon 
     style={{
            transform: [
              {
                rotate: animatingState
                  ? '0deg' /* set this to initially 0.5 or '0deg' */,
                  : wiggleInterpol 
              },
            ],
    ...
```